# Randomise strings in mysql

Tags: mysql, random

I've a string in mysql that i want to randomise so that every time i run the query, i get different results.

The sample string

`$str = '4_127','2_84','2_85';`

So, i will pass it to the `ORDER BY` clause to randomise results.

```
SELECT `MY_SEARCH_PARAMS` FROM `mytable` WHERE `MY_WHERE_CONDTIONS` ORDER BY
FIELD( CONCAT( property_id,"_",catalog_id ), '4_127','2_84','2_85' ), `id` ASC;
```

I need a way so that the order of the string contents is changed everytime.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `$str = '4_127','2_84','2_85';` the actual string or you have tree strings which are `4_127`, `2_84` and `2_85`?

Comment: It is the actual string.

Comment: do you have ` '4_127','2_84','2_85'` values in your table???

Comment: @jcho360 No, they are the values of `concat`ing... `property_id` `catalog_id` as shown in the query. 4_127: 4 is property_id, 127 is catalog_id and so on...

Comment: what you are asking doesn't make sense in MySQL, you are trying to order by 3 items that don't belong to the Table, I guess it would be better do it with help of another programming language like PHP

Comment: @jcho360 See the query properly. They _do_ belong to the table and are **stored in 2 fields**, which are being queried by using `concat`.

Comment: if they do belong to the table why don't you use a `order by rand()`?

Comment: Where will this `rand()` come? After the `FIELD(...)` or before. I had tried that to no avail, that's why i posted this question. But, don't think this is going to help me much.

Comment: So that's the actual string... Then, what is that `$str = ` prefix that gets stripped? Is a fixed prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Really? That's very confusing behaviour. What are you trying to achieve?

Nevertheless even if you use code like this it's at least better to randomise them in the php script (I am assuming you are using php).

```
$str_array = array('4_127','2_84','2_85');
shuffle($str_array);
$str = implode(", ",$str_array)
```

Comment: Confusing it is, sure. But that's how projects change :) Yes, if nothing else, i might do it in PHP.

Comment: Why do you want that to be handled by MySQL ?

Comment: There are quite a few other fields/conditions that depend on it.